# How to eliminate and show only non-duplicate records

Tags: sql

See the below table:

```
col1     col2
----     ----
 1    |   a      
 2    |   b    
 3    |   c
 4    |   a
 5    |   d
 6    |   b
 7    |   e
```

Now I want to show only the non-duplicate records. which means 3,5,7.

How to write a query to get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table
GROUP BY col2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: You got my question exactly. Thanks!

Comment: Actualy it is a bad idea to include into SELECT list column that doens't have aggregate or not included into GROUP BY. It can work in mysql, but it is not good.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.*
FROM 
(
SELECT col2
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY col2
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
) A,
YOURTABLE B
WHERE A.col2 = B.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(*) as cnt,col1, col2
FROM table
GROUP BY col2
HAVING cnt = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Believe this is clear and correct enough:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    col2 IN (SELECT col2 FROM table GROUP BY col2 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```